# Adding transaction support to embedded jetty/GWT RemoteServiceServlet without Spring?

Tags: gwt, web-applications, aop, aspectj, embedded-jetty

GWT's servlet implementation has onBefore/onAfterDeserialization which would give me a hook with which to start and stop transactions without doing anything fancy, however those methods don't allow me to properly check for error conditions after the service method got invoked, I just have access to the serialized return value, not directly to any exception that might have been thrown, so deciding whether to roll back or not is not possible that way without rewriting parts the GWT servlet.

I was thinking about using aspectj's compile-time weaving. However, this does not work with Netbeans' compile-on-save feature because the module needs to be recompiled using the aspectj compiler.

How about LTW (load-time-weaving)? Is there any way (or example) to add LTW to the webapp container without using the Spring framework?

I was also thinking about using AOP based on Java dynamic proxies, ie. to put a proxy in front of the servlet. Again, the question arises how to tell the Jetty WebApp container to load the proxy instead of the original servlet.

Or is there any ready-to-use solution out there already?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could overwrite a combination of
`public String processCall(RPCRequest rpcRequest)` from `RemoteServiceServlet` and `RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse` to do what you want.

Not ideal, as you need to copy/paste a few lines of code, but they really are only a few.
I myself hit the same problems as I needed some customizations, and relevant methods didn't had the access modifier that I needed, so I ended up copy/pasting some portions.

I can't comment on the rest of your question, but I don't expect to find any ready-to-use solutions, as GWT-RPC doesn't seem to have any *new* fans out there; just people maintaining legacy systems. Therefore, I expect that you either don't find anything or find solutions that are no longer maintained.